# What is the root cause of "Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am going through the definitive [ROR tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#book_menu) as I am completely new to Rails.

When I run rails -v I get:

```
Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

My Gemfile contains:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.0.0.pre2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
gem 'polyglot', '0.3.2'
gem 'rake', '0.9.2'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'annotate', '2.4.0'
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc8'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc8'
end

gem 'autotest-standalone', :require => 'autotest'
gem 'autotest-rails-pure'
gem 'term-ansicolor'
gem 'turn'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

I've tried bundle install, rvmsudo gem install rake which returns:

```
Successfully installed rake-0.9.2
1 gem installed
```

One would imagine that would take care of it.

I also tried rvmsudo gem install rails, uninstalling  everything and starting over and this error keeps coming back sooner or later.

Comment: Can you try a `gem list rake` ? You will see all installed versions of the gems. If you see an other version of rake the problem could come from there, try uninstall the wrong versions.

Comment: gem list rake returns:
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
rake (0.9.2)

so I have only one version installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bundle exec rails -v` do it for you?

Comment: Hello um facing the same problem and why um getting this error Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing rake gem 0.8.x . I think there are some inconsistencies between 0.9.x andn 0.8.x for supporting other gems.